# Use $(TargetName) or $(ProjectName) in OutputPath of csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I am trying to set the `<OutputPath>` of my C# project to the name of the project, but when the project builds, it only resolves `$(SolutionDir)` and not `$(ProjectName)` or preferably `$(TargetName)`.

How can I use the target name in my `<OutputPath>`?

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\Release\plugins\$(ProjectName)</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I see property name is different `MSBuildProjectName` , from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found that you can use the defined properties that are used in the propertygroups in the complete csproj.

So I used `$(AssemblyName)`:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\Release\plugins\$(AssemblyName)</OutputPath>
```